# Problematic positioning of editable rotated text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a table with certain text-cells being vertical(rotated) but having great **problems getting consistent positioning**. I've got the basic outline working. It was a bit off in IE(big suprise) but figured I could fix that with some kind of browser-conditional .
The real problem however is that the text, which by the way is editable moves a bit when selected the first time. It's a bit hard to explain so you can see for yourself:
http://gdurl.com/eM_F

In Chrome it always occurs when tabbing between the fields to focus them the first time, but not clicking. And *sometimes* when typing in them after having clicked them.

In IE it always occurs when the field gets focus the first time.

I'd like to solve this somehow using css, but if required I could use javascript/jquery. I did try calling `focus()` on them when the page loads so that their position will be consistent, but it didn't work.
Also tried setting the contenteditable-attribute to false, and setting a tabindex in the hope of setting the contenteditable to true when it gets focus would fix it but even if contenteditable is false it still behaves like that when tabbed to.

Comment: did you try finding ** width and height of focussed div?**
Log them over console and I'm sure you'll find the problem and solution yourself.

CSS does not have a resolution to this but **Javascript/Jquery definitely does.**
Please check it out. **For IE you'll have a different sets of style/ css classes** altogether to achieve this.

Comment: @MilchePatern That's not the problem.

Comment: @Doorknob It is not **the** problem, but it will help narrow situational behaviors (like IE quirk). In order to test layout and compare it from different browsers, i need a DTD.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. Apparently the problem was the "overflow:hidden". Either removing it or setting it to the same element as the rotation did the trick. But I'm still working on getting this to work consistently cross-browser. I'm coming back with a more thorough answer.